# How can I extract a .tlb from an .exe?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, typelib

I have a COM application that I want to use, but I only have the .exe from that app. Is there a way to extract the .tlb from that .exe?

I tried with `tlbexp filename.exe` from Visual Studio Command Prompt, but I get an error and I don't know why: `TlbExp : error TX0000 : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`
I am using Visual Studio 2012 with C++.

**Edit:**

The .exe is in C++, later I saw that tlbexp is for .NET. This is why it didn't work. But I still need to find a way to extract the .tlb from C++ .exe.

Comment: tlbexp is only usable with a .Net executable, is this the case? If not use a tool like oleview to see if the typelib is embedded as a resource

Comment: You are using the wrong utility, use Tlbimp.exe instead.

Comment: @HansPassant actually Tlbimp.exe is also .Net and I need C++, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: "Open With": https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/08/21/open-with/ screenshots 2 and 3

Comment: If you want to invoke the COM interfaces in your .EXE from .NET you can use tlbimp with the .EXE as input to create an interop assembly. Using managed extensions for C++ it's possible to access the COM interfaces via both managed and unmanaged C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this utility "[ResourcesExtract](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html)"  Just check the type libraries option:

[image]

It does now work on all cases but it works for many dlls and exe

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to extract a type library assuming  the EXE/DLL actually has a resource with its typelib. That's not a given, even for a COM server.

Assuming that a typelib does exist within the file, then Visual Studio itself can be used to extract the type library in as a TLB file from an EXE or DLL (or OCX).

Here's an example doing this for Microsoft Common Controls using Visual Studio 2022.

First, run Visual Studio. Then open the EXE or DLL using <kbd>Open With</kbd>:

[image]

Make sure the resource editor is the chosen tool and click <kbd>OK</kbd>:

[image]

Once open, right click the resource under the `TYPELIB` node and *Export* it to a file:

[image]

*The binary file saved here is in `TLB` format.* You can open it, for example, using OLEView.

---

(This answer inspired by comments on the question left by Roman R.  Jan 14, 2016 at 13:34)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev good point, I've added that to the answer. I think it was implicit in the question that the OP at least assumed their binary did have one, but definitely best to call that out explicitly for anyone else who comes along.

Answer (score 0):

> the same can be done programmatically with standard file resource
> management API, `LoadResource` and friends, then `WriteFile`.

(from comment left by Roman R. Jan 14, 2016 at 13:39)